# AWK мат преобразования над многоколоночными данными

Tags: математика, awk

Я работаю с многоколоночными файлами следующего формата

```
# input.csv from the folder 10V1_cne_lig12
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500 # this is dG(min)
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
4, 150, -4.1200
```

Требуется обработать каждую строку этого CSV, чтобы сократить ее до двух столбцов: оставив первую колонку с номером строки (ID) + результаматематической операции (f), выполненной с числами в столбцах второй и третей колонки POP и dG:

```
f(ID)= sqrt(((dG(ID)+10)/10)^2+((POP(ID)-240)/240))^2)
```

где dG (ID) - это значение dG ($ 3) текущий строки, POP (ID) - это значение POP ($ 2) ктекущей строки. В итоге этот скрипт должен обрабатывать исходный файл (с 3коланками) в output.csv ( с двумя колонками)

```
# output.csv
ID, f
1,  f(ID1)
2,  f(ID2)
3,  f(ID3)
4,  f(ID4)
```

Буду благодарен за пример AWK кода позволяющий циклически применить вышеуказанное мат преобразование к каждой строке исходного файла?

Comment: Да верно , я забыл ещё одну скобку ! Там в первом члене преобразования в числителе   dGmîn учавствует со значением dG из текущей строки то есть для первой строки весь член будет =dGmin -dGmin / dGmin ==0

Comment: пропущенные скобки добавлены в оба члена! ,)

Comment: + фото формулы ,)